# Is every client that uses ids3, mandatorly requires SSL certificate?

Tags: identityserver3

I just want to understand, whether the client that uses the Ids3, mandatory to have the SSL Certificates ? I having below domains or the application that uses the ids3. Do I need to go for different SSL Certificates ? What is recommended ?

1. abc.example.com.au
2. abc.example.com.nz
3. abc.api.module.example.com
4. abc.api.global.example.com

Your inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

IdentityServer does not demand SSL. But you need SSL on all your sites for transport protection of course.

You don't necessarily need a separate SSL cert for each site - you can buy wildcard or multi-site certs. For different top level domains you need separate certs of course.